# Copying file from local to SharePoint server location

Tags: delphi, file, sharepoint, copy

Now on my PC I can use explorer to open a location on our SP server (location eg http://sp.myhost.com/site/Documents/). And from there I can copy/paste a file from eg my C:\ drive.

I need to replicate the copy process progmatically. FileCopy() doesn't do it - seems to be the http:// bit that's causing problems!

Comment: Ironic that I find this question because I just started working with SharePoint the other day and I myself was pondering the exact same thing (except I already know from common sense you can't do a simple FileCopy() for this)

Comment: It's trivial to do this with .net. So, C# or PowerShell. Would that do you?

Comment: No, has to be Delphi. I don't have time to start learning even more new things to develop in! I'm already learning Python to teach to my GCSE students, relearning Pascal for A-level, SharePoint for VLE development and JavaScript for the SP stuff!

Comment: It's pretty much a one liner in .net. Not sure if there's a good Delphi wrapper.

Comment: If you can give me the .net thing I may at least have something to start looking at? I know nothing about .net :)

Comment: Well One of the big things about .net is commonly performed tasks such as this (that is with Microsoft products) are already encapsulated and can be integrated into any language that supports .net.

Comment: You need `SPWeb.GetFile` to get an `SPFile` object. Then you can call `OpenBinary` on the file and then save the byte array to disk. Some websearches with those terms should get you there. I won't write an answer since you state that it "has to be Delphi".

Comment: Ok, there's a start. I have to be honest I don't really understand what .net is or does :)

Comment: Don't know if this will fool Delpi's FileCopy, but you could try to mount the SharePoint folder as a drive. Then your copy can just take m:\blah instead of http:// etc.

Comment: Thank Erik - though dont have admin priveleges on the machines so don't think it would work. I think that when I'm on the school network I can access it with \\this\kind\of\access which should work a-ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the server allow **WebDAV** access? If yes, there are WebDAV clients for Delphi available, including [Indy 10](http://atozedsoftware.newsgroups.archived.at/indy.general/200511/0511224307.html).

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are not using BLOB storage all SharePoint files are stored in the database as BLOB objects.

When you access your files with explorer you are using windows service which is reading files from SharePoiont and render it to you. This way you can copy and paste as soon as donwload them from an to SharePoint manually.

To be able to do this automatically you should achive this using the next SP API code:

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://testsite.dev"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Debug.txt"))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int) fs.Length);

                    SPList list = web.GetList("Lists/Test AAD");
                    SPFile f = list.RootFolder.Files.Add("/Shared Documents/"+Path.GetFileName(fs.Name), buffer);
                }
            }
        }
```

This will add new "Debug.txt" file to the "Shared Documents" library read from the disk C. To do this for each file just loop through each file in the folder. You can open web only once and do the loop each time when you add file...

Hope it helps,

Andrew